# Accessing nginx on a virtual machine from another computer

Tags: nginx, debian, vagrant

I am currently following a tutorial on using chef.  The teacher uses vagrant to set up a virtual machine, his vagrant file contains this:

config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"

I didn't want to use vagrant, so created a VM from scratch and implemented all the other parts of his vagrant file manually.  However I'm not quite sure what this exactly does.  He then goes onto updating his hosts file in /etc/hosts to include:

```
33.33.33.10 kayak.test
```

Then he can access his nginx server using "kayak.test" in his browser on another computer.  I can access my server using my private IP address "192.168.169.129" in the browser, but I added this that name to my hosts file and I can not access it in the same way.  My host file now looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       jack.www.jack.co.uk jack

192.168.169.129   jack.test

::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

But I cannot access jack.test in the browser of my other computer.  What do I need to do to get the same functionality as he has?

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: Yep, that works fine.  Just can't get it to work with anything in the hosts file

Comment: probably the problem is in nginx.conf. Is nginx processing requests to jack.test domain name?

Comment: I have this in my nginx.conf:

server_name jack.test

Comment: What kind of browser are you using? Any proxy?

Comment: please show this command output from you computer: grep "hosts" /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

Comment: I am using unicorn... Not sure this is the problem though, as it wasn't working before I implemented unicorn

Comment: ok, when you **ping jack.test** is it resolving this name to ip?

Comment: It does when I ping it from my server that is running nginx, but not from remote computer....  I get ------ ping: cannot resolve jack.test: Unknown host when trying to ping from my remote computer

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue related to Avahi if you have it on your system. 
RFC2206 explicitly defines .test .example .localhost an other TLD's as invalid:
http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt

As a possible workaround you can change the line in /etc/nsswitch.conf this way:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns mdns4
```

Do not forget to restart avahi daemon after this.

Source of the workaround: http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal

Comment: Sorry, no luck.  I changed it to jack.srv with no luck

Comment: please run this **getent ahosts jack.srv**

Comment: On my server it returns: 
192.168.169.129 STREAM jack.srv
192.168.169.129 DGRAM  
192.168.169.129 RAW

Comment: But at the same time **ping jack.srv** can't resolve this name?

Comment: I can on my server, but not from my other laptop which is where I need to access it from

Comment: So **getent ahosts jack.srv** on your laptop returns nothing?

Comment: dscacheutil -q host -a name jack.srv returns nothing on my mac

Comment: What the version of OS X? Have you tried to flush DNS cache?

Comment: Yosemite..  Still no luck after resetting my DNS cache.  Are you sure I don't need to set something else up?  I'm not sure I'm emulating what vagrant is doing when executing this: config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"

Comment: I believe it's Yosemite /etc/hosts file issue . But I made the same change on my mac and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AndreySabitov you made me see where I was going wrong.

I was getting confused and updating my servers /etc/hosts file, rather than my laptops. Therefore when I updated my laptops etc/hosts file with

192.168.169.129 jack.srv

I can now access that server from my laptop.

Thanks!